# Generate a list with two unique elements with specific length

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, numpy

I would like to generate below mentioned list in python.
I would like have a function with where we can decide length of list and unique elements.

Expected function:
l1 = [0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7, 0.3, 0.7]

where the first element of the list is 0.3, second element is 0.7, then 0.3, after that 0.7 and repeat the sequence till it have length 8.

Comment: @Divakar pls share the code

Comment: [value1, value2]  *  n  ?

Comment: @Divakar Thanks. yes the link answers my question